# How to deal with single quotes in json format in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'd like to convert json format into pandas df. Sample of json is as below:

```
{'asin': '0615208479', 'description': "By now we all know the benefits of exercise for the body. It's the only real fountain of youth! The same is true for the brain. Take your brain to the gym several times a week and you can improve, regain and prevent memory loss. Discover the world of brain fitness through BrainAerboics.\nThe program was designed by a medical team and is backed with mounting research proving it works. It is believed to be the only one that combines the three crucial elements required for optimal brain fitness.", 'title': 'Brain Fitness Exercises Software', 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41kbZB047NL._SY300_.jpg', 'salesRank': {'Health & Personal Care': 1346973}, 'categories': [['Health & Personal Care', 'Personal Care']]}
```

1. I've tried:

   ```
   df = pd.read_json('test.json',lines=True)
   ```

   This is not working because my json here have single quotes, which is not standard json format.
2. So I've also tried simple shell script to convert all single quotes into double:

   ```
   cat test.json|sed "s/'/\"/g"
   ```

   This is also not working, because json contains review texts which contains sth like `"It's the only real"`; so we can't rudely convert all single quotes into double.
3. Then I tried to think what about convert directly with keeping single quotes:

   ```
   with open ('test.json') as f:
       s = f.read()
   print(ast.literal_eval(s))
   ```

But I got error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

at `'categories': [['Health & Personal Care', 'Personal Care']]`

Comment: That's not valid json.

Comment: I know. Because of it's not double quotes? Then what to do?

Comment: Create actual JSON in the first place.

Comment: It's not valid JSON - your best bet is to find a sufficiently lenient JSON parser and then use that to re-dump your JSON formatted correctly

Comment: Just hacking away at it the following worked: `ast.literal_eval(s.strip().replace('\n','\\n'))` but you should *reallly really* fix the *source of this problem*. Whoever is making this file and calling it a JSON is messing up pretty bad. Instead of finding a hacky solution, fix the root of the issue

Comment: Not everyone is lucky enough to have that kind of influence over the source of their data. If you're one of the lucky ones, sure, change it, but if you have to live with it, you have to live with it.

Comment: If you know the data isn't JSON, then why does your title and tagging say "JSON"?

Comment: Where does this input come from?

Comment: I downloaded from online, it's actually Amazon reviews, it's named as "xxx.json";

Comment: If someone saved a GIF file with a .jpeg name, would you ask people why you can't parse it as a JPEG?

Comment: I would say, it's not STANDARD json format. But similar to json?

Comment: Very hard to believe that Amazon would create non-JSON and call it JSON. Or even just create this at all. What's the URL? How did you download it?

Answer (score 4):

This question shouldn't use "JSON" anywhere in its title or tagging, since this data *isn't JSON*.

That said, `ast.literal_eval()` works fine, if you escape the newline literals.

```
s='''{'asin': '0615208479', 'description': "By now we all know the benefits of exercise for the body. It's the only real fountain of youth! The same is true for the brain. Take your brain to the gym several times a week and you can improve, regain and prevent memory loss. Discover the world of brain fitness through BrainAerboics.\nThe program was designed by a medical team and is backed with mounting research proving it works. It is believed to be the only one that combines the three crucial elements required for optimal brain fitness.", 'title': 'Brain Fitness Exercises Software', 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41kbZB047NL._SY300_.jpg', 'salesRank': {'Health & Personal Care': 1346973}, 'categories': [['Health & Personal Care', 'Personal Care']]}'''

import ast
ast.literal_eval(s.replace('\n', '\\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks! If it's not JSON, then what is it? Similar to JSON? This is data I downloaded from online.

Comment: I think that's far too overly pedantic. It's a slight variation of json, is not unrealistic other people might encounter it and when they search for possible answers, they'll quite sensibly search for json. The fact that it's somewhat malformed json does not make json inappropriate for either the title or the tag - these reflect human language, not a programming one.

Comment: Words have meanings. You might say "in a JSON-like format" if you mean to make things fuzzy for human use, but if it doesn't comply with the JSON specification, it's not JSON.